# MFMailComposeViewController sending Email

Tags: objective-c, email

I dont have a problem with the code itself, just with the understanding of MFMailComposeViewController
First: How can I add my adress as the sender address?

When I click send, an email will be send to the recipients. And the email comes from my Email account.

But when I check my boxes, the email i sent from the app is stucking in the outbox.

error: "host does not allow relaying" how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to first question is : You cannot add sender address from your application. Your sender address will be same as configured in Mail app of iPhone. You need to configured your email account in Mail app of iPhone.

iOS does not allow to setup mail account in your application.

Once you will configure proper mail account in Mail app, you will get rid off such errors.

Comment: Hm I added an mail account, clicked on AOL and added my account details. Then I get this relaying error

Comment: Firstly check is your Mail app working properly?? Is all configurations right?? If that is not working then there must be configuration issues.

Comment: I would give alot of people votes, but it always tells me 'requires 15 reputation to vote'

Comment: I clicked on the tickbox under your post now its green. is it accepting? sorry I am not familiar with it